# Crystal Report showing Disk full

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

When i clicked on the button, the crystal report is supposed to call a stored procedure from database and then display a crystal report, but the result is

> Disk full. Details: error Error in File Report {4CoDE2B7-99AF-......}.rpt: File I/O error. Details: error

I can generate the report previously, the report generated would be quite big, larger than 200MB. Is the size causing the problem?

I tried searching fot tmp files, but the temp folder is empty (would it show empty folder when i hover over if i dont have the permission to view it?).

Also, I put my remote query timeout in the connection properties to 10000 because sometimes when i update table it show query timeout expired. Is this causing the issue?

I also notice in SQL Server, there are more than 5 "audit logout" before "batch complete" in the task of calling the stored procedure (exec sp_report).

Hope someone can answer my questions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, *is* the disk full?

Comment: @AlexK. nope. there's plenty of spaces left. definitely more than the size of exported report in pdf. would rpt file generated for display be much much more bigger than exported pdf report?